# Get selectedrow primary key on a gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, entity-framework-4

Please i have a problem trying to get the primary key of a gridview control in a web application bounded by an entitydata source.I have a table called staff and this table has about 25 columns on it.The primary key of this table consist of a combination of two columns which is column [StaffID] and column [SchoolID].
I used the entitydatasource control to hook up to the table.I did not select all the columns i just selected four of the columns.Below is the markup of the entitydatasource control.

```
        ContextTypeName="DEMOWEBAPPLICATION.PriSecDbEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
        AutoGenerateOrderByClause="true" 
        EntitySetName="Staffs" EntityTypeFilter="Staff" 
        Select="it.[StaffID], it.[SchoolID], it.[Surname], it.[FirstName]">
        <OrderByParameters>
        <asp:Parameter 
        DefaultValue="StaffID" />

        </OrderByParameters>
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

I bounded this to a gridview control.My question is i want a situation when i click on a row on the gridview i will be able to show the different columns from my staff table on different textbox control(for example i will be able to do something like this txtSurname.text=newStaff.name and so on) and i will be able to edit and updated it and it will updates on the database. I have been trying to create an object of staff and get the primary key column by doing this in vb.net
      Dim newStaff As Staff = DirectCast(grdLoadStaffDetails.SelectedPersistedDataKey("StaffID"), Staff) in the gridview selectedindexchanged event handler but it throws up an invalid cast execption hour. I have been pulling out my hair out for the past five hours. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the  **DataKeyNames="StaffID"** with your primary key columna name.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvwAllUserInfo" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="StaffID"
                OnRowEditing="GridView_RowEditing" AllowPaging="True"
```

get the staffid in code

```
mygridview.SelectedIndex = CInt(e.NewEditIndex)
StaffID= CInt(mygridview.SelectedDataKey.Value)
```